# Erorr When running powershell Script

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am running the script as below:

Get-MessageTrace -StartDate (Get-Date).Adddays(-9) -EndDate (Get-Date) -SenderAddress amir@worldheritageexhibitions.com -PageSize 5000 Get-MessageTraceDetail Export-CSV C:"All email.CSV" –NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

However I am getting the error as below

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'MessageTraceId'  Cannot convert value "C:\All emails.CSV" to type
"System.Guid". Error: "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code properly. Now it looks as if all is in one line or is it?

Comment: Theo I am trying to combine these switches for a message trace command but i am not sure if this would be the right way to combine it...

I got these switches from " https://o365info.com/using-get-messagetrace-powershell-command-for-viewing-and-exporting-information-on-mail-sent-and-received-exchange-online-part-2-2/"

Comment: That's not what I asked. Please format it so we can see what you are actually trying to run here..